# Pass database value in form (django)

Tags: python, django

My `form.py`:

```
class BannerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=32)
    #Affiliazione = forms.CharField(disabled = True, initial='red') #in original question
    #affiliation = forms.ModelChoiceField(Affiliation.objects.all(),
    #widget=forms.HiddenInput(), initial=Affiliation.objects.get(id=1))  #in original question
    Affiliazione = forms.CharField(disabled = True, required=False) #added after first answer
    affiliation = forms.ModelChoiceField(Affiliation.objects.all(),
    widget=forms.HiddenInput()) #added after first answer
```

The 'Affiliazione' field display 'red' but it isn't saved because [Disabled controls cannot be successful](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#disabled). The 'affiliation' field actually pass the data but is hidden. They together give what I want (a disabled field that pass data so the user can see the value but can't change it).

The problem is I don't like to hardcode that values ('red' and 'id=1'). I have the 'Options' class in models where I choose the value to pass but I don't know how... I think it's a silly question, sorry, but someone can help me?

My `models.py`:

```
class Options(models.Model):
    new_affiliation = models.ForeignKey('Affiliation')

class Affiliation(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32, unique=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Banner(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32, unique=True)
    affiliation = models.ForeignKey(Affiliation)
```

Edit. My `View.py`:

```
def add_banner(request):
    # A HTTP POST?
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = BannerForm(request.POST)
        print('form is post') #control
        # Have we been provided with a valid form?
        if form.is_valid():
            print('form is valid') #control
            # Save the new banner to the database.
            banner = form.save(commit=False)
            #some irrilevant code here
            form.save(commit=True)
            print('form salvato') #control
            # Now call the homepage() view.
            # The user will be shown the homepage.
            return homepage(request)
        else:
            # The supplied form contained errors - just print them to the terminal
            print (form.errors)
    else:
        # If the request was not a POST, display the form to enter details
        #form = BannerForm(request.POST) #in original question
        #initial_value = 'red' #added after first answer
        #init = Affiliation.objects.get(id=1) #added after first answer
        form = BannerForm(request.POST or None, initial={
        'affiliation': Campaign_Options.new_regent_affiliation}) #added after first answer
    # Bad form (or form details), no form supplied...
    # Render the form with error messages (if any).
    print ('fine')
    return render(request, 'core/add_banner.html', {'form': form})
```

My `add_banner.html`:

```
  {% csrf_token %}
  {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
  {{ hidden }}
  {% endfor %}

  {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
    {{ field.errors }}
    {{ field.label }}
    {{ field }}
    {{ field.help_text }}
    <br />
  {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if I don't quite get the intention of your form, but for the sake of answering your question, you could pass the initial value from your views when you initialize the form, this will make the value flexible:

```
def your_view(request):
    # get the string for affilizione by applying your logic here
    # initial_value = 'red'
    form = BannerForm(request.POST or None, initial={'Affiliazione': initial_value})
```

Comment: My form serve to permit the user to create new Banner (there are other irrilevant fields). The user should see the affiliation value but should'nt be able to change it. Your view don't pass nothing to my form... the field stay void

Comment: Then you might need to tweak your front end as well. Render the field like: `{{ field.label }}: {{ field.value }} ` would give you only the value instead of rendering the widget.

Comment: That don't work either... It give "Nome: None" "Affiliazione: None" without textbox in both. I have edited my first post

Comment: But are you sure there isn't some easier way to pass the initial data in the form... something like init=Options.new_affiliation and then     Affiliazione = forms.CharField(disabled = True, initial=init)

Comment: I worked on it and now it work but it's the same like before... just I was initializing from the form and you from the view... the problem is the same: I don't like to hardcode that values ('red' and 'id=1'). I have the 'Options' class in models where I choose the value to pass but I don't know how. So, how can I pass the value of the field 'new_affiliation' from the 'Options' class to the fields 'Affiliazione' and 'affiliation' in the BannerForm or in the 'add_banner' view?

Comment: I would definite myvariable= read field 'new affiliation' in Options and use this variable to initialize my  two fields... maybe i need two variable (a string for the charfield and an integer for the ChoiceField)?

Comment: I don't know why you don't like to use the `initial`, but it's the standard way to initialize a form with default value. Also it's not hard coded, you didn't hard code anything, or I should say there's nothing wrong if you hardcode the default value.

Comment: Sorry, maybe i'm using the wrong word... I would like to use initialize but it isn't working how expected. What I don't like is to write the initial values on the form (or view) because sometime they change and I don't want go searching for them on 2-3000 line of code for modify... I create a Options class for set the initial values from the Admin panel but I don't know how to pass these value to the form (or view). I think it's something very elementary

Comment: Then the field `affiliation` which is hidden holds the true value and field `Affiliazione` just display something? If so `Affiliazione` shouldn't be a form field, just pass it to the template and render it manually somewhere in the forms.

Comment: You are right about Affiliazione but how your modify can help me? Someone deleted my comment but the problem is how to pass my values from Options to the fields, everywhere these fields can be... move a field in template don't help me like didn't help me move a field to views. I want something like initial=myvariable but I don't know how to definite myvariable

Comment: You need to give more information about `Option`. What does that do? Why cannot query from `Option` field and get the `new_affiliation` and feed it to the form with `initial={'affiliation': option.new_affilication}`? It's the same concept isn't it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102282/discussion-between-fabio-and-shang-wang).